# How can I manage subscriptions to Facebook friends 2012?

Tags: facebook

In the past this question had been quite straightforward and easy to solve, however I've just spent the last 30 minutes searching for what I'm about to describe but currently it seems to not exist!

On Facebook you have friends, by default you are subscribed to all of these friends news feed updates as "Most Updates".

You can modify this to your own personal choice to be either: "All Updates/Most Updates/Only Important"

**What I am looking for**

I am looking for the page that shows you the status of how you are subscribed to your friends. I want to find the friends I have applied "Only Important" to and possibly revoke that change.

In the past you could do it like so: http://betterfacebook.net/blog/blog/2011/10/10/manage-your-friend-subscriptions-to-see-all-their-updates/

But my page of "subscriptions" just looks like this, even though I have a few hundred friends:

[image: Empty Subscriptions]

Am I missing something here?

The other method is mouseovering the "News Feed" tab thing on your home feed and clicking "Edit" button, this is meant to show all of your blocked or hidden friends, but this doesn't show any of my friends that I've hidden either?!

[image: Edit Facebook News Feed]

Answer (score 1):

First you need to go to the "all friends" page at:
https://www.facebook.com/me/friends

Then go through  following steps, for each friend

1. hover over your friends name, and wait for the popup screen
2. hover over the friends button
3. click the settings option
4. select which updates you want to see

Comment: Is there no way to view all friends current settings though? This way will take a very long time.

Comment: not that i know of

Answer (score 0):

Facebook frequently changes features and its quite annoying to see few good ones being withdrawn. I miss the feature which used to have a list of people whom you have not assigned to any list (i.e. those who have not been categorized yet).

The Subscriptions feature you are looking at now, only lists people whom you have explicitly "Subscribed to" - similar to how you would follow someone on Twitter. Except that here, it means that you are not friends with the person, but only subscribe to their public updates.

Comment: What I want to do is change/view the update status of my **current friends**. I don't want to have to got through every single profile to view the update status I have set.

Comment: Yes I get it. But I don't think its possible now. Its very similar to what I'm looking for from sometime (w.r.t lists).